# Android layout - inside a chain, distribute some elements, but pack some others

Tags: android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I've read [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/#constrain-chain), but I can't figure out how to do this.

What I have is a regular chain with all the elements, chain mode "spread inside":
[image]

What I want is the buttons with the up and down arrows packed to the right side, and the "4" text spread evenly in the remaining space:

[image]

My xml:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sel_rep_1"
            android:layout_width="11dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(exercise.set1Reps)}"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:visibility="@{exercise.isActive &amp;&amp; !exercise.isTimedExercise? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sp_sel_exer"
            tools:text="4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sel_rep_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(exercise.set2Reps)}"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:visibility="@{exercise.isActive &amp;&amp; !exercise.isTimedExercise? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_1"
            tools:text="4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sel_rep_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(exercise.set3Reps)}"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:visibility="@{exercise.isActive &amp;&amp; !exercise.isTimedExercise? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_sel_increase_reps_small"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_2"
            tools:text="4" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sel_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(exercise.setTime)}"
            android:visibility="@{exercise.isActive &amp;&amp; exercise.isTimedExercise? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/b_sel_increase_reps_small"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_sel_increase_reps_small"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/b_sel_increase_reps_small"
            tools:text="30"
            tools:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_sel_increase_reps_small"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.incrementSet(exercise, true)}"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="↑"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:visibility="@{exercise.isActive? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b_sel_reduce_reps_small"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_sel_rep_3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_sel_reduce_reps_small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.decrementSet(exercise, true)}"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="↓"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:visibility="@{cbActiveExer.checked? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/b_sel_increase_reps_small"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/b_sel_increase_reps_small"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/b_sel_increase_reps_small" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the buttons from the chain and have them stick to the end of the parent by only specifying their `end` constraints. Now keep the `TextViews` in a chain with the default chainstyle (`spread`) and constrain its `start` to parent's `start` and its `end` to up-arrow's `start`.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textview2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textview3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textview1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview3"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/increase"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textview2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/increase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/decrease"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/decrease"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image: Result]